# Ocean displacement map not showing waves

Tags: texturing, modifiers, edit-mode, vector-mapping

I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CwJrb3vjAaA He gets the waves on the ocean but I don't. I successfully made waves on a plane but not on the circle (see video). Basically I have to tile the plane onto the circle.  I have attached screenshots.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you say in the question what is the actual thing you are asking about? Thanks.

Comment: @Patisawesome200  better?

Comment: I don't see an edit on my side, but I will assume that you are asking about how to make the Ocean Modifier work on a circle. Is that correct?

Comment: @Patisawesome200 no the video tells me to map bake of the ocean modifier from a plane onto the circle.

Answer (score 1):

The circle does not have enough geometry.

Displacement in Blender works by modifying existing geometry on the object. Your circle definitely does not have enough existing geometry to make displacement visible. This is an easy fix, just apply a subdivision surface modifier, or select all the edges and subdivide them in the edge context menu.

Additionally, I see that you are in Texture Preview mode. Note that displacement will only show as bump in that mode, and in order to actually displace the mesh you need to switch to rendered view mode in cycles and make sure that displacement and bump are both rendered.

Comment: ok, the video said to do 2 subsurf modifiers, and I did that, but it still isn't working.

Comment: do I need to apply it? um I don't think I did that XD

Comment: Yes, you do need to apply it.

Comment: I applied it and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: @liaiwen did you go to Material->Settings->Surface->Displacement-> set it to "Displacement and Bump"?

Answer (score 0):

apply the subdivision modifier and stick this displacement to bdsf normal section ... hope it's work

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: The BDSF normal input will not actually displace your mesh but instead will shade the mesh as if it was displaced. You will need to connect it to the material output's displacement input in order to truly displace the mesh.

Comment: @EricXue How exactly do I do that?

Comment: @EricXue I already have the vector displacment set to displacement